# SoapFault: Technical: PX000040 : BEA-382505 : XPath statement prod

Tags: php, soap, xpath, lumen

de verdad necesito urgentemente de su apoyo, actualmente me estoy conectando a un web service de un cliente el cual me ha entregado 2 rutas WSDL para conectarme.
La primera me conecta sin problema, pero al aplicar la misma estructura para consumir el otro servicio me arroja el siguiente erroe:

> Technical: PX000040 : BEA-382505 : XPath statement produced no nodes
>   to validate

Alguien sabe a que se debe este error?

este es mi codigo:

```
public function name()
{
$client = new SoapClient(“servicio?wsdl”, array(
‘location’ => “url a conectarme”,
));

$params = array(
‘objetodelmetodo’ => array(
‘parametro 1’ => ‘string’,
‘parametro 2’ => ‘string’,
‘parametro 3’ => int,
‘parametro 4’ => int,
‘parametro 5’ => int,
‘parametro 6’ => int
)
);

$response = $client->Metodo($params);
return response()->json($response);
}
```

Comment: Si agregas en un browser el url "servicio?wsdl" del ws que tiene problema, que muestra?

Comment: Me muestra el xml perfecto, de hecho estoy usando soapUI para probar la petición, y allí me funciona perfecto, debe ser algo malo que tengo en el código, pero lo raro es que tengo la misma estructura para otro wsdl del mismo cliente y si me funciona

Comment: Estas usando el mismo parser para ambas? @YonikerPlaza

Comment: correcto @Jorgesys , mantengo la misma estructura del código solo cambia la url, el método y los parámetros que le envío.

Comment: intenta esto en el método para comprobar que te estás conectando correctamente, sino existe la posibilidad que el servicio en si requiera una llave, login, algo que no te hayan suministrado
`$v = new SoapClient("http://escribe.toda.la.url/service?WSDL"); var_dump($v->__getFunctions())`

Comment: Si @FranciscoHahn en efecto la url me arroja la información que necesito cuando quiero ver sus métodos, de hecho tengo un controlador aparte que hace la conexión para validar que lo este haciendo bien y si es así, el error me aparece es cuando intento llamar al método (el cual es solo uno de ese servicio), según el error esta en esta linea: $response = $client->Metodo($params);

Comment: Los métodos de un servicio SOAP en php se llaman así desde php 6 sino me equivoco  `$cliente = new SoapClient("ubicacion/servicio?WSDL"); $result = $cliente->nombreDelMetodo(array("parametro1" => "val1".. "parametron" => "valn"))`, fijate que siempre los nombres de los parámetros sean exactamente igual a los que espera el servicio, si por ejemplo el parámetro 1 se llama "nombrePersona" y en el array envías "nombrepersona", no te funcionará. Si necesitas más claridad de los nombres de los parámetros y funciones usa `var_dump($cliente->__getTypes())`

Comment: Hola @FranciscoHahn gracias por tus respuestas, tienes razón he revisado el nombre del método letra por letra y esta tal cual al igual que los parámetros que le envío, ya he hecho de todo y el mismo error siempre, la verdad estoy pegado con esto llevo días investigando sin poder avanzar, la verdad se consigue muy poco sobre este error. :(

Comment: a ver, usa getTypes y copia (o edita tu pregunta) con la respuesta que da respecto a el método que te tira problemas, deberia decir esa linea `responseNombreMetodo NombreMetodo params(parametro 1 etc...)` algo así.